# Which python implementation support inspect.currentframe()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cpython

According to following note in python documentation, inspect.currentframe() is not supported in some implementations.

> inspect.currentframe()
>
> Return the frame object for the caller’s stack frame.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This function relies on Python stack
> frame support in the interpreter, which isn’t guaranteed to exist in
> all implementations of Python. If running in an implementation without
> Python stack frame support this function returns None.

Which implementations of Python does not support it?

Comment: Just to be clear (because of how you've tagged the question), this isn't referring to different *versions* of CPython; it's referring to [non-CPython implementations of Python](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/).